# tokenise on white space ONLY | sklearn - TfidfVectorizer | Python

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

Is there a way for me to use `TfidfVectorizer()` from `sklearn.feature_extraction.text` such that

1. NOTHING is removed
2. The ONLY token separator is white space

In the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) it states the argument `token_pattern` takes a regular expression denoting what constitutes a “token”. It further states by default **(1) punctuation is completely ignored** and **(2) always treated as a token separator.**

I've managed to deal with (1) by having `token_pattern = r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b|!|\?|\"|\'|.|-|_"` *(am I missing any punctuation btw?)* but I haven't been able to deal with (2). I'm unfamilar with regex so I'm guessing it has something to do with that? Below is an example

```
sentence_list = ['-docstart-', 
                'eu rejects german call to boycott british lamb .',
                 'brussels 1996-08-22']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern = r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b|!|\?|\"|\'|.|-|_")
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentence_list)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

```
### What I get
[' ', '-', '.', '08', '1996', '22', 'boycott', 'british', 'brussels', 'call', 'docstart', 'eu', 'german', 'lamb', 'rejects', 'to']

### What I want
['.', '1996-08-22', 'boycott', 'british', 'brussels', 'call', '-docstart-', 'eu', 'german', 'lamb', 'rejects', 'to']
```

So essentially what I really want is just for the token separator to be ONLY white space and for NOTHING ELSE to happen. Thanks for taking your time to read this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `(?u)` is only needed for Python 2.x. If you need to get non-whitespace chunks as tokens, just use `r'\S+'`. If you need to separate punctuation, use `r'\w+|[^\w\s]'` (yeah, ``r'(?u)\w+|[^\w\s]'`` for Python 2)

Comment: Wow so simple thank you... I really appreciate you taking the time to answer this!